# Get lazyLoadException in Hibernate with MySql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I`m having problem with lazyLoadException.

I´ve looked in the google but things dosn´t worked with.

My configuration file

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=root
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nfehost
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
javax.persistence.validation.mode=none
hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=true
hibernate.connection.pool_size=1
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider
current_session_context_class=org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
```

My openSessionViewFilter class

```
package com.nfehost.view.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.nfehost.dao.HibernateSessionFactory;
import com.nfehost.util.NullUtil;

@WebFilter(urlPatterns="/*")
public class OpenSessionInViewFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Transaction transaction = null;

        try {

            Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            transaction.commit();

        } finally {

            if (NullUtil.isNull(transaction) && transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

    }   

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">

    <display-name>nfehost</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- timeout sessao -->
     <session-config>
       <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
     </session-config>

     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

     <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
     </context-param>

     <listener>
        <listener-class>com.nfehost.framework.CoerceToZeroListener</listener-class>
     </listener>

     <listener>
        <listener-class>com.nfehost.framework.EmailTimerListener</listener-class>
     </listener>    

     <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
     </context-param>

     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/resource/spring/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

     <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
     </listener>

     <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/resource/spring/spring-*.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <error-page>
      <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type >
      <location>/pageError.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

My stackTrace

```
Jan 31, 2014 6:01:56 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
Advertência: could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at com.nfehost.model.Arquivo_$$_javassist_3.toString(Arquivo_$$_javassist_3.java)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.nfehost.model.NotaFiscal.toString(NotaFiscal.java:32)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.nfehost.view.NotaFiscalListBean.toString(NotaFiscalListBean.java:16)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.subformat(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.util.MessageFactory.get(MessageFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:245)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:271)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:818)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.nfehost.view.filter.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don´t know what to because I don´t have any @oneToMany relationship or @manyToMany in my model classes.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "arquivo_nota_fiscal")
public class Arquivo extends Persistent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3255362119912486510L;

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "data_registro", updatable = false)
    private Date dataRegistro;

    @Lob
    //@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name = "conteudo", columnDefinition = "longtext")
    private String conteudo;

}
```

Arquivo.class

I use lombok, because it doesn´t have getter and setter.

NotaFiscal.class

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, exclude = {"arquivoNotaFiscal","emitente","destinatario"})
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "nota_fiscal")
public class NotaFiscal extends Persistent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7632933705216815478L;

    public enum TipoOperacao {

        ENTRADA(0, "Entrada"), 
        SAIDA(1, "Saída");

        @Getter
        private final int index;
        @Getter 
        private final String descricao;

        private TipoOperacao(int index, String descricao) {
            this.index = index;
            this.descricao = descricao;
        }

        public static TipoOperacao valueOf(int index) {
            for(TipoOperacao tipoOperacao : TipoOperacao.values()) {
                if (tipoOperacao.index == index) {
                    return tipoOperacao;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public enum TipoEmissao {

        NORMAL(1, "Normal - emissão normal"), 
        FS(2, "Contingência FS - emissão em contingência com impressão do DANFE em Formulário de Segurança"), 
        SCAN(3, "Contingência SCAN - emissão em contingência no Sistema de Contingência do Ambiente Nacional - SCAN"), 
        DPEC(4,"Contingência DPEC - emissão em contingência com envio da Declaração Prévia de Emissão em Contingência - DPEC"), 
        FS_DA(5, "Contingência FS-DA - emissão em contingência com impressão do DANFE em Formulário de Segurança para Impressão de Documento Auxiliar de Documento Fiscal");

        @Getter
        private final int index;
        @Getter 
        private final String descricao;

        private TipoEmissao(int index, String descricao) {
            this.index = index;
            this.descricao = descricao;
        }

        public static TipoEmissao valueOf(int index) {
            for(TipoEmissao tipoEmissao : TipoEmissao.values()) {
                if (tipoEmissao.index == index) {
                    return tipoEmissao;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public enum FinalidadeEmissao {

        NORMAL(1, "NF-e normal"), 
        AJUSTE(2, "NF-e complementar"), 
        COMPLEMENTAR(3, "NF-e de ajuste");

        @Getter 
        private int index;
        @Getter 
        private final String descricao;

        private FinalidadeEmissao(int index, String descricao) {
            this.index = index;
            this.descricao = descricao;
        }

        public static FinalidadeEmissao valueOf(int index) {
            for(FinalidadeEmissao finalidadeEmissao : FinalidadeEmissao.values()) {
                if (finalidadeEmissao.index == index) {
                    return finalidadeEmissao;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public enum IdentificadorProcessoEmissao {

        APLICATIVO_CONTRIBUINTE(0, "Emissão de NF-e com aplicativo do contribuinte"), 
        AVULSA_FISCO(1, "Emissão de NF-e avulsa pelo Fisco"), 
        AVULSA_CONTRIBUINTE(2, "Emissão de NF-e avulsa, pelo contribuinte com seu certificado digital, através do site do Fisco"), 
        CONTRIBUINTE_FISCO(3, "Emissão NF-e pelo contribuinte com aplicativo fornecido pelo Fisco");

        @Getter 
        private final int index;
        @Getter 
        private final String descricao;

        private IdentificadorProcessoEmissao(int index, String descricao) {
            this.index = index;
            this.descricao = descricao;
        }

        public static IdentificadorProcessoEmissao valueOf(int index) {
            for(IdentificadorProcessoEmissao identificadorProcessoEmissao : IdentificadorProcessoEmissao.values()) {
                if (identificadorProcessoEmissao.index == index) {
                    return identificadorProcessoEmissao;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Size(max = 60)
    @Column(name = "descricao_natureza_operacao")
    private String descricaoNaturezaOperacao;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "serie")
    private Integer serie;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "numero")
    private Integer numero;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "data_emissao")
    private Date dataEmissao;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "data_hora_entrada_ou_saida_produto")
    private Date dataHoraEntradaOuSaidaProduto;

    @Type(type = TipoOperacaoType.TYPE)
    @Column(name = "tipo_operacao", columnDefinition = "int", length = 1)
    private TipoOperacao tipoOperacao;

    @Type(type = TipoEmissaoType.TYPE)
    @Column(name = "tipo_emissao", columnDefinition = "int", length = 1)
    private TipoEmissao tipoEmissao;

    @Type(type = FinalidadeEmissaoType.TYPE)
    @Column(name = "finalidade_emissao", columnDefinition = "int", length = 1)
    private FinalidadeEmissao finalidadeEmissao;

    @Type(type = IdentificadorProcessoEmissaoType.TYPE)
    @Column(name = "identificador_processo_emissao", columnDefinition = "int", length = 1)
    private IdentificadorProcessoEmissao identificadorProcessoEmissao;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "valor_icms")
    private BigDecimal valorIcms;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "valor_nota_fiscal")
    private BigDecimal valorNotaFiscal;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "chave_nfe", length = 44)
    private String chaveNfe;

    @Size(max = 28)
    @Column(name = "digest_value")
    private String digestValue;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "emitente_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Emitente emitente;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "destinatario_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Destinatario destinatario;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "arquivo_nota_fiscal_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Arquivo arquivoNotaFiscal;

}
```

Comment: Can you paste the entity Arquivo_ here

Comment: what does Persistent have?

Comment: NotaFiscal might have the mapping to Arquivo? from the logs.

Comment: Yes...I´m going to put it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lazy on Arquivo . You are trying to fetch in a non session context. you may change it to EAGER.

Or after fetching NotaFiscal do Hibernate.initialize(notaFiscal.getArquivoNotaFiscal());

Comment: I have a field, `conteudo`, it´s very big...It´s a long string, may a let it lazy or not?

Comment: Yes, you can add lazy on the string property conteudo. That should also work. And make arquivoNotaFiscal EAGER. But again, if you make conteudo as lazy, you may not be able to fetch it in outofsession context, you may hit this issue again.

Comment: Ok...but I read in internet for this problem, openSessionViewFilter pattern will stop with this problem...but don´t stop

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there in below code off Arquivo class.

**@Lob
 //@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @Column(name = "conteudo", columnDefinition = "longtext") 
private String conteudo;**

The column displayed above is marked with @Lob the default fetch mode for column marked with this annotation is LAZY. As per stack trace the toString() method is get called. The toString() method tried to access the all the fields and get LAZY exception for 'conteudo' field.

**org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185) at com.nfehost.model.Arquivo_$$_javassist_3.toString(Arquivo_$$_javassist_3.java)**

**Solution:** 
Either you should change the fetch mode of that column or define toString() method without using that column.

Comment: Why redefine toString() method?